# OnItemClick in listview show image in another activity ,without any path/src

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Listview in my app which is populated with textview and imageview by a custom adapter and with custom objects, now i want that when i click the image on the listview it should open in another activity as full screen, how should i do that ?

i have a API of socket connection which brings a Byte array named image , and i add this to the list view.

here is the code-->

```
@Override
                public void onBinaryMessage(byte[] image)
                {


                Bitmap receivedImage=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
                    float scale=1;

                int width  = receivedImage.getWidth();
                    int height = receivedImage.getHeight();
                    float scaleHeight = (float)height/(float)200;
                    float scaleWidth  = (float)width /(float)200;
                    if (scaleWidth < scaleHeight) 
                        {scale = scaleHeight;}
                    else
                    {
                        scale = scaleWidth;
                    }

                   Bitmap bitmaped = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(receivedImage, (int)(width/scale), (int)(height/scale), true);
                addImage(new Message(bitmaped,false,false));
```

Now when on Click what should i pass to the intent as i can get this image which is in the list view , according to my current code i can toast the Text in the listview textView element.
here is the code-- >

```
  listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.v("Module Item Trigger", "Module item was triggered");


                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this is ==>",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the Activity with the `ListView` you can do this in the `onItemClickListener` once you have the `byte[]` from the selected `Bitmap`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myListActivity., ImageActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putByteArray("image", imageArray);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Basically, that starts the other Activity, passing the `byte[]` in the `Bundle`.

Then in the Activity that displays the full screen image, you can get the `byte[]` out of the `Bundle` and decode it into a `Bitmap`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        byte[] image = bundle.getByteArray("image");
        Bitmap receivedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);

        // Do something with receivedImage
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but i think passing huge data over intent is not a good method and it will surely give an error, what you say ?

Comment: For large images, you're right.  You'll want to use either a static field or a singleton class.  You could also write to a file.  Singletons might be the best option, google "Singletons in Android" to find out more.

Comment: Thank you , but when i try to getDrawingCache from imageview in list i get a null value ? can you help in that ?

Comment: Try `imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`